# Universal Sentence Encoder load error "Error: SavedModel file does not exist at..."

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

I installed Uiniversal Sentence Encoder (Tensorflow 2) in 2 virtual environment with Ananconda. One is on Mac, anther is on Ubuntu.

All worked with following:

```
  module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4" 
  model = hub.load(module_url)
```

Installed with:

```
conda create -n my-tf2-env python=3.6 tensorflow
conda init bash
conda activate my-tf2-env
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-hub
```

But, for unknown reason after 3 weeks, Mac does not work with following error which fails at:

```
model = hub.load(module_url)

Error: SavedModel file does not exist at: /var/folders/99/8rwn_9hx3jj9x3qz6yf0j2f00000gp/T/tfhub_modules/063d866c06683311b44b4992fd46003be952409c/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

On Mac, I recreated new env with same procedure but has same error.

On Ubuntu, all works well.

I want to know how to fix Mac. Thank you for help.

What I attempted on Mac is that I tried to download "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4" to local drive and load it from local drive in future, not from web url. This process was not finished and not successful yet. I don't remember if there is anything downloaded to Mac with this attempt, that might corrupted Tensorflow-hub on login user account of my Mac.

Comment: It seems delete the file will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error usually occurs when the `saved_model.pb` is not present in the path specified in the `module_url`.

For example, if we consider the Folder structure as shown in the screenshot below,

[image]

The code,

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4" 
model = hub.load(module_url)
```

and

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

module_url = "/home/mothukuru/Downloads/Hub" 
model = hub.load(module_url)
```

work successfully.

But if `saved_model.pb` is not present in that Folder as shown below,

[image]

Executing the code,

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

module_url = "/home/mothukuru/Downloads/Hub" 
model = hub.load(module_url)
```

results in the below error,

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /home/mothukuru/Downloads/Hub/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

In your specific case, executing the code while the Download of the Model was in progress might have resulted in the error.

As stated in the comment, deleting the Downloaded File can fix the problem.

Please let me know if this answer has not resolved your issue and I will be happy to modify it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Delete the file does solve the problem. Since download take long time and you don't kill the download process when restart, this issue could happen too easily, and there is no clear error message. Wish this could be improved.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I resolved it by deleting the 063d866c06683311b44b4992fd46003 folder. Is the mac cleaning these files up?

Comment: I am having the same problem, but I need more instruction than "deleting the Download File". How do I delete the download file?

Comment: Yes indeed, same thing happened to me and deleting the folder then rerunning the code worked. Thanks and +1 !

Answer (score 0):

TF Published some [additional guidelines on caching models](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/caching) apparently in response to [questions about this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/850).

In my case, I was running this locally on Mac via a jupyter notebook.

I was not sure how to "Delete the download file" as suggest in the other answer, but I found this resolved my issue:

https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/caching#reading_from_remote_storage

> **Reading from remote storage**
>
> Users can instruct the `tensorflow_hub`
> library to directly read models from remote storage (GCS) instead of
> downloading the models locally with
>
> `os.environ["TFHUB_MODEL_LOAD_FORMAT"] = "UNCOMPRESSED"`
>
> or by setting the command-line flag `--tfhub_model_load_format` to `UNCOMPRESSED`. This way, no caching directory is needed, which is especially helpful in environments that provide little disk space but a fast internet connection.

I ran that command in my notebook, and then the error was immediately resolved.

Note: I assume this is slower, especially if you do not have a fast internet connection, since what you are doing is telling the program to not locally cache (store) a copy and to just download it on demand.